# How to identify if BIOS is infected?

Tags: bios

How to identify if BIOS is infected with malware? Is there a way to extract content of a BIOS chip?

Comment: Welcome to this website. Your question is really TOO broad and it needs a whole book to answer to it. It is the same as when you ask: *How can I know my computer is infected ?*.  Not much thing that an anti-virus or detection tool can do when it comes to BIOS infection.